# Cloning git repository from docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

To let docker access my git repository, I have created a personal access token. And embedded command

> RUN git clone -b docker https://token:x-oauth-basic@github.com:user/repo.git

into my dockerfile. I got it from [1](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-a-docker-container-to-automatically-pull-from-github-using-oauth/)

But it is throwing error:

> remote: Not found
>   fatal: repository 'https://{token}:x-oauth-asic@github.com:user/repo.git/' not found

Although I have given permission to access my repo.

I have googled the problem and there is an option to copy ssh key to container but I want to use oauth mechanism. But it is not working, please tell me know what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The format for using a git token is below

```
git clone https://<token>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

or

```
git clone https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

Comment: Which image are you inheriting the docker file from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the token as the username. You don't seem to do that here.
Reference: https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth